# Improve this reflection bashing code

Tags: c#, reflection, serialization

I have implemented an `IDataContractSurrogate` to enable serialization of `ImmutableList<T>` (from the Microsoft Immutable Collections BCL)  using the `DataContractSerialization` framework.

The code is a bit wild using reflection and compiling of delegates. Are there any subtle improvements or obvious over engineering problems here?

This is a follow-up from a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955441/how-to-serialize-deserialize-immutable-list-type-in-c-sharp), but further improvements feel like code review rather than specific questions.

**TESTCASE**

```
using FluentAssertions;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Xunit;

namespace ReactiveUI.Ext.Spec
{
    [DataContract(Name="Node", Namespace="http://foo.com/")]
    class Node
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public string Name;
    }

    [DataContract(Name="Fixture", Namespace="http://foo.com/")]
    class FixtureType
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public ImmutableList<Node> Nodes;

        public FixtureType(){
            Nodes = ImmutableList<Node>.Empty.AddRange( new []
            { new Node(){Name="A"}
            , new Node(){Name="B"}
            , new Node(){Name="C"}
            });
        }
    }

    public class ImmutableSurrogateSpec
    {  
        public static string ToXML(object obj)
            {
                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
                {
                    DataContractSerializer serializer =
                      new DataContractSerializer
                          ( obj.GetType()
                          , new DataContractSerializerSettings() { DataContractSurrogate = new ImmutableSurrogateSerializer() }
                          );
                    serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
                    writer.Flush();
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        public static T Load<T>(Stream data)
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer
                  ( typeof(T)
                  , new DataContractSerializerSettings() { DataContractSurrogate = new ImmutableSurrogateSerializer() }
                  );
            return (T)ser.ReadObject(data);
        }

        public static T Load<T>(string data)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
            {
                return Load<T>(stream);
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ShouldWork()
        {
            var o = new FixtureType();

            var s = ToXML(o);

            var oo = Load<FixtureType>(s);

            oo.Nodes.Count().Should().Be(3);
            var names = oo.Nodes.Select(n => n.Name).ToList();
            names.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(new[]{"A", "B", "C"});                
        }
    }
}
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ReactiveUI.Ext
{
    class ImmutableListListConverter<T>
    {
        public static ImmutableList<T> ToImmutable( List<T> list )
        {
            return ImmutableList<T>.Empty.AddRange(list);
        }

        public static List<T> ToList(ImmutableList<T> list){
            return list.ToList();
        }

        public static object ToImmutable( object list )
        {
            return ToImmutable(( List<T> ) list);
        }

        public static object ToList(object list){
            return ToList(( ImmutableList<T> ) list);
        }
    }

    static class ImmutableListListConverter {
        static ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, Type>, Func<object,object>> _MethodCache 
            = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, Type>, Func<object,object>>();

        public static Func<object,object> CreateMethod( string name, Type genericType )
        {
            var key = Tuple.Create(name, genericType);
            if ( !_MethodCache.ContainsKey(key) )
            {
                _MethodCache[key] = typeof(ImmutableListListConverter<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(new []{genericType})
                    .GetMethod(name, new []{typeof(object)})
                    .MakeLambda();
            }
            return _MethodCache[key];
        }
        public static Func<object,object> ToImmutableMethod( Type targetType )
        {
            return ImmutableListListConverter.CreateMethod("ToImmutable", targetType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
        }

        public static Func<object,object> ToListMethod( Type targetType )
        {
            return ImmutableListListConverter.CreateMethod("ToList", targetType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
        }

        private static Func<object,object> MakeLambda(this MethodInfo method )
        {
            return (Func<object,object>) method.CreateDelegate(Expression.GetDelegateType(
            (from parameter in method.GetParameters() select parameter.ParameterType)
            .Concat(new[] { method.ReturnType })
            .ToArray()));
        }   
    }

    public class ImmutableSurrogateSerializer : IDataContractSurrogate
    {
        static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type> _TypeCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type>();

        public Type GetDataContractType( Type targetType )
        {
            if ( _TypeCache.ContainsKey(targetType) )
            {
                return _TypeCache[targetType];
            }

            if(targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ImmutableList<>)) 
            {
                return _TypeCache[targetType] 
                    = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(targetType.GetGenericArguments());
            }
            else
            {
                return targetType;
            }
        }

        public object GetDeserializedObject( object obj, Type targetType )
        {
            if ( _TypeCache.ContainsKey(targetType) )
            {
               return ImmutableListListConverter.ToImmutableMethod(targetType)(obj);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public object GetObjectToSerialize( object obj, Type targetType )
        {
            if ( targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ImmutableList<>) )
            {
               return ImmutableListListConverter.ToListMethod(targetType)(obj);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public object GetCustomDataToExport( Type clrType, Type dataContractType )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetCustomDataToExport( System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes( System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Type> customDataTypes )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport( string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType( System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ImmutableSurrogateSerializer() { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This actually looks pretty nice and I am bookmarking it. :)

Two tiny details, which are probably a waste of time:

1. I would personally (probably) make the `ImmutableListListConverter<T>` a private class inside of the `ImmutableListListConverter`, since it's an implementation detail of the latter class.
2. I usually try to avoid looking up a hash table multiple times, even though the performance difference is usually negligible. In your case, `ImmutableSurrogateSerializer.GetDataContractType` could probably avoid looking at the dictionary most of the time by doing the `if` guard at the beginning and then doing the lookup/insertion in a single step. Also, the indexer right after `ContainsKey` results in that unnecessary second lookup. Note that this is what I find **simpler to read**, not because the performance difference is anything but negligible:

   ```
   public Type GetDataContractType(Type t)
   {
      // if this is not an immutable list, we can just skip the rest immediately 
      if (!t.IsGenericType || t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(ImmutableList<>))
      { 
          return type;
      }

      // get the result through the cache
      return _TypeCache.GetOrAdd(t, t => typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t.GetGenericArguments()));
   }
   ```

But as I've written, apart from that, it's a really nice approach. Proper de/serialization of immutable types is something I've been looking for since .NET 2.0 and the plain old `XmlSerializer`.